SQLAlchemy scoped_session provides the same session for each test
I'm a bit confused with SQLAlchemy scoped_session. It looks like session object is not recreated with every test case, even though I set up database fixture with 'function' scope.
I have an app factory and database factory which looks like follows:
# __init__.py

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # some config here
    with app.app_context():
        from database.database_factory import init_db
        # db variable is set in the class with database models like below
        # db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base, session_options={'autoflush': True})
        init_db(db)
    # some config here
    return app

-----------------------------------------------------------------

# database_factory.py

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

Engine = None
Session = None


def init_db(db_object: SQLAlchemy):
    db_object.create_all()
    global Session
    global Engine
    Session = db_object.session
    Engine = db_object.engine


I also have some view functions which import Session object from database_factory.py to operate on database.
And then I have some tests. I set them up with fixtures like this:
# conftest.py

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def app():
    app = create_app()
    yield app


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def client(app):
    with app.test_client() as test_client:
        return test_client


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def app_ctx(app):
    with app.app_context():
        set_up_db(app)
        yield
        teardown_db(app)


def set_up_db(test_app):
    from database.database_factory import Session, Engine
    test_app.Session = Session
    test_app.Engine = Engine
    test_user = User(email=USER_EMAIL, password=ph.hash(USER_PASSWORD), phone=USER_PHONE)
    test_app.Session.add(test_user)
    test_app.Session.commit()

def teardown_db(test_app):
    test_app.Session.remove()
    test_app.Engine.dispose()
    shutil.rmtree('./instance')

The problem is with below test case which is parametrized with 3 parameters, so it is executed 3 times. I would expect that for each time, new database session will be used.
Test passes 2 times, but 1 time always fails.
For clarification:

CHOOSE_GROUP - requires one row in the db table
CHOOSE_PLACE - requires more than one row in the db table
ADD_NEW_PLACE - requires empty db table

# test.py

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("app_ctx")
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("content", [CHOOSE_GROUP, CHOOSE_PLACE, ADD_NEW_PLACE])
    def test_login_view_with_correct_credentials1(self, app, client, content):
        add_temp_places(content, app.Session)
        app.Session.commit()
        response = client.post(path='/login', data={'email': USER_EMAIL, 'password': USER_PASSWORD, 'submit': True},
                               follow_redirects=True)
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert content in response.data

def add_temp_places(content, session: scoped_session):
    try:
        if content == CHOOSE_PLACE:
            session.add_all([MOCK_PLACE_1, MOCK_PLACE_2])
        if content == CHOOSE_GROUP:
            session.add(MOCK_PLACE_1)
    except Exception:
        raise

When I did some print outs to see the status of scoped_session, it looks like the object remains the same for all test cases, which I believe causing the issue with incorrect database cleanup before the next test case.
session before test: <sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session object at 0x000001ADA50820D0>
PASSED [ 33%]session after test: <sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session object at 0x000001ADA50820D0>
session before test: <sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session object at 0x000001ADA50820D0>
PASSED [ 66%]session after test: <sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session object at 0x000001ADA50820D0>
session before test: <sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session object at 0x000001ADA50820D0>
FAILED [100%]

Am I configuring database for tests in a wrong way?

It seems that you set up the database only once, leading to the tests using a single session. Consider modifying set_up_db as a fixture with the scope function. This way it will use a new session each test case. Also important to create a new session each time in this fixture. You can't import the existing session from database_factory.py because that one is initialized before fixture applied. There was a similar question but only about fastapi https://stackoverflow.com/a/78675130/25598148.
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def init_test_db(app):
    app.Session = new_session_here <- create a new session here 
    app.Engine = new_engine_here <- create a new engine here 
    test_user = User(email=USER_EMAIL, password=ph.hash(USER_PASSWORD), phone=USER_PHONE)
    app.Session.add(test_user)
    app.Session.commit()
    
    yield 

    app.Session.remove()
    app.Engine.dispose()
    shutil.rmtree('./instance')

It is also important to use the same app you created for tests. In you case it should be this one:
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def app():
    app = create_app()
    yield app


Thank you for you reply but I'm afraid that's not it. I did as you suggested but I'm still having the same problem. Even though I set up function scope of initi_test_db, scoped_session remains the same for each test function call.

Yes, you are right. I overlooked that I was importing Session and Engine from the database_factory.py. In short, there was a single session for all tests because it is intialaized for all project before the tests. I updated the answer to give more context about it.

I don't understand how can I create new session within this fixture.
I can't call init_app() because then I got an error that this app is already bind to SQLAlchemy extension. If I just call create_all() then this does not change anything.
To my understanding function scoped app() fixture should provide completely new app with database session. Inside create_app() function, there is another function called which creates session. Why would I need to create new session inside init_test_db() fixture?
